# How to derive the formula for a line integral?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

In the [Wikipedia derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Derivation) they use the Mean Value Theorem (MVT) to approximate the distance between two points of a function $\vec{r}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ by saying that $|\vec{r}(t_{i} + \Delta t) - \vec{r}(t_{i})| \approx|\vec{r}'(t_{i})|\Delta t$

I have two questions regarding this:

1. How can they use the MVT here for a vector valued function? I thought that there was no analog for the MVT of a vector valued function
2. Assuming, that you can use the MVT here why are we using the point $t_{i}$ as an input into $\vec{r}'$? I thought the MVT said that there is a point in the interval $c \in [t_{i},t_{i} + \Delta t]$ such that $|\vec{r}(t_{i} + \Delta t) - \vec{r}(t_{i})| = |\vec{r}'(c)|\Delta t$

(i.e. why is it $|\vec{r}'(t_{i})|$ and not $|\vec{r}'(c)|$?)

Is it just because we are assuming the interval $[t_{i},t_{i} + \Delta t]$ is small and thus $|\vec{r}'(t_{i})|\Delta t$ would be a good approximation to $|\vec{r}(t_{i} + \Delta t) - \vec{r}(t_{i})|$?

Comment: The symbol $\approx$ is not exact. Here, it basically hides the following fact: $ (r(t_i+\Delta t) - r(t_i) - r'(t_i) \Delta t) / \Delta t \to 0 $ for $\Delta t \to 0$.